# Running a line in 1 hour intervals in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a espeak based talking clock completely in python

I want to know how to run

```
spk.speak('It is now <time>')
```

Each time the system hits time's like 12:00 1:00 etc

Comment: What OS are you on?  Its rarely a good idea to write something like this yourself.  `cron` or the equivalent on your system would be a better option.

Comment: Perhaps the OP wants a cross-platform solution or doesn't have access to something like `cron`.

Comment: Yeah, No cron.. Just standalone :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import time
while True:
    # sleep for the remaining seconds until the next hour
    time.sleep(3600-time.time()%3600)
    spk.speak('It is now <time>')
```

Comment: Thought about leap seconds? Not every hour has 3600 seconds!

Answer (score 6):

You didn't specify what operating system you are using but running things at an interval is the job of some [`cron`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)-like process on Linux and Unix. On Windows, there is [windows task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler).

You set these systems up to run your comand at intervals.

For example, this cron entry runs the script every hour:

`0 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/myuser/somefile.py`

You an also use:

`@hourly /usr/bin/python /home/myuser/somefile.py`

`@hourly` is an alias for `0 * * * *`